# CheckboxField Tick color

Tags: blackberry

My employers want a BlackBerry which looks and feels exactly like their current app to reduce training time. Currently they're using 4.5 and the project is in 5.0 which as you can imagine presents many problems with this requirement.

There is one very minor issue I have with the CheckboxField and that's the color of the tick. In 4.5 the tick is green where as in 5.0 it's blue. I've asked my employers to just deal with the blue tick but they said 'no, it must be green!'.

Does anyone know an easy way to achieve this without rewriting the entire paint class?

You may think this sounds like a silly/superficial question and I'd agree with you but unfortunately for me; it's a requirement they just won't budge on!

Thanks,

Graeme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. you can Override `applyTheme()` in `MainScreen` and left that empty.

   protected void applyTheme(Graphics arg0, boolean arg1) {
       }
2. you can use [Characters.BALLOT_BOX](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Characters.html#BALLOT_BOX) and [Characters.BALLOT_BOX_WITH_CHECK](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Characters.html#BALLOT_BOX_WITH_CHECK) for creating your custom checkbox.